# Print 100's of documents to 35 different printers daily

Tags: pdf, printing, printer, routing

Imagine having ~35 clients that **demand** that their reports be sent to printers (not faxes, not email), but nice color high resolution printers. You have 20 to 30 reports per client .... so around 600-900 print jobs

What software/setup can I establish to help a single operator send 100's of documents to 35 different printers daily.

I'm looking for capability

- Send PDF A to Printer 23 (manually if needed)
- Check to see if all jobs succeeded

Advanced capabilities would be:

- Associate folder with a printer
- Monitor folder for PDF's print, archive

Solutions Tried So Far

- Google Cloud Print - Too difficult to track progress.  Reported false positive on print success.

Please advise.  Thank YOU!

Comment: I have the feeling that this is an X -> Y problem. Why would you ever want to print thousands of pages daily? What problem are you actually trying to solve? (Rather than: "I think I have some way of solving it. how do I do $way"?

Comment: Imagine having 30 clients that demand that their reports be sent to printers (not faxes), but nice color high resolution printers.  You have 20 to 30 reports per client .... so around 600-900 print jobs.

Comment: I would suggest a PDF printer in combination with email (which also prevents the need for those client to scan all the printout when they need to go to their archives).

Comment: You need to implement printer pooling. Windows server has this functionality built in, and offers a lot of great print management tools. Use 2012, it's a huge improvement over 2008.
Printer pooling is also available from several print management software packages. Start by looking at papercut and their competitors. JetDirect Admin could be worth checking out depending on your fleet composition.

Comment: I am curious to know what you have done on your own so far. By the way this question is worded, this seems to be hypothetical or a homework question. Is this a real problem? If yes, then please explain what you have done so far and where you have gotten stuck.

Comment: Google Chrome offers cloud printing so you could set up all of those printers under one account and have yourself a blast.

Comment: hennes - The client demands the documents to be sent to a printer.  Clearly email would be better.  @alex-atkinson - Thank you.  I was aware of Papercut but not JetDirect.  Thanks for the 2012 knowledge!  charlieRB So far we have tried Google Print.  It was a HUGE flop.  Print Jobs quit 1/2 through, things were difficult to track.  monkeyzeus - We tried Google Cloud Print, it failed.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be possible with [Ricoh Print&Share](http://www.printandshare.info) (commercial solution, 30-day trail)

Based on what exactly you want to do, as I can't see your configuration, I can only suggest some configurations, but ofcourse you could easily adapt and modify them.

**Print the same document to 2 printers (or more printers)?**
Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZg0byBj_w0&list=PLDF2C2AD95B2B2FC2&index=35

**or do you need to combine it with batch printers?**
[image]

**or do you want to execute specific printer channels based on triggers (e.g. number of pages, colour, when some text, label or barcode is found)?**
[image]

**or do you want to have multiple profiles per printer or group of printers and select the profiles based on a value for the printers?**
video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvTly9qXQMI&list=PLDF2C2AD95B2B2FC2&index=38

It really depends on what you really want to do exactly, but I think it should be possible.
There was an example of someone who uses this application to print 1 file to about 10 or 15 printers on remote location (his printers are accessible via network because the offices are connected) and he has several printer channels with batch printers, to further add specific logo's for specific office-locations. Just did a check but can't seem to find that link anymore.

*(I'm affiliated with the product)*